# Python ImportError: cannot import name itemgetter

Tags: python, urllib

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2013, 12:43:04) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 33, in <module>
  from urlparse import urljoin as basejoin
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 118, in <module>
  from collections import namedtuple
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 9, in <module>
  from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
ImportError: cannot import name itemgetter
```

This issue occurs when I run `import urllib`. Python version is 2.7. Is this a Python's version problem? Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a module with the name of "operator" in your code?

Comment: I just run python shell, not python code ...

Comment: Do you have a file named `operator.py` or `operator.pyc` in the current directory?

Comment: `import operator;print operator.__file__` What's the output for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a file called operator.py in the current directory, so `import operator` is picking up your module and not the Python standard library module `operator`.

You should rename your file to not conflict with Python's standard library.

Comment: (Credit to @Ashwini Chaudhary for being first to pick up on this).

Comment: Not necessarily a file. I get the same error with a dir named operator.